# Haskell, reverse two elements in list?

Tags: list, haskell

i want to take a list and always reverse two elements.
Example:

input 1: `[1,2,3,4,5]`, output 1: `[2,1,4,3,5]`

input 2: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` output 2: `[2,1,4,3,6,5]`

I tried it with pattern matching:

```
g1 [] = []
g1 (x:y:xs) = y: x: g1 xs
```

But it says:

```
*Main> g1 [1,2,3]
*** Exception: test.hs:(13,1)-(14,27): Non-exhaustive patterns in function g1
g1
```

Has anybody an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add a case for one-element lists which you will hit if the list contains an odd number of elements.

Comment: What should be done for a list containing a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you apply this, for instance on the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`. It runs as follows:

```
g1 [1,2,3,4,5]
= 1 : 2 : g1 [3,4,5]
          = 4 : 3 : g1 [5]
```

and there is no pattern defined for the list contain **one single element** (here `[5]`). Based on your first example nothing should be done in such case except *emitting* the element. So you have to add the case:

```
g1 [x] = [x]
```

Or the entire function definition:

```
g1 [] = []
g1 [x] = [x]
g1 (x:y:xs) = y: x: g1 xs
```

Comment: Ahh now i understand! I didnt know how Haskell is using the function to solve the problem... I thank you!